# How do I write a custom validation to ensure 2 or more elements do not have the value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have three phone numbers I want to validate: mobile, home, and work

```
<input id="mobile_phone" name="mobile_phone">
<input id="home_phone" name="home_phone">
<input id="work_phone" name="work_phone">

// plugin
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneNotEqual", function(value, element, param) {

   $(param).each(function() {

        return value != this.value;

   });

}, "The mobile, home, and work phone must be different.");





// validate
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        mobile_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: '#home_phone, #work_phone'
        },
        home_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: '#mobile_phone, #work_phone'
        },
        work_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: '#mobile_phone, #home_phone'
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to specific with the error message where if the error is for mobile, the message would say home and work number cannot be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Is there a way to specific with the error message where if the error is for mobile, the message would say home and work number cannot be the same?"*

Simply over-ride your default message by using the `messages` option within `.validate()`.  Also note the revised formatting of your parameters...

```
// validate
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        mobile_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: ['#home_phone', '#work_phone']
        },
        home_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: ['#mobile_phone', '#work_phone']
        },
        work_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: ['#mobile_phone', '#home_phone']
        }
    },
    messages: {
        mobile_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: "custom message 1"
        },
        home_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: "custom message 2"
        },
        work_phone: {
            phoneNotEqual: "custom message 3"
        }
    }
});
```

You'll also need to fix your custom method as your loop will end on the first iteration.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneNotEqual", function(value, element, param) {
    var flag = true;
    $(param).each(function(i) {
        if (value == $(param[i]).val()) {
            flag = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return this.optional(element) || flag;
}, "The default message");
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/sjr3tdfz/**

Comment: Your messages are wrong. For `mobile_phone`, it should say `mobile cannot be the same as home or work`.

Comment: @Barmar, my messages are only based on what the OP specifically asked for... _"if the error is for mobile, the message would say home and work number cannot be the same"_  ~ the point here is that he can change these messages into whatever he wants.  I edited my answer to make that point more clear.

Comment: Sparky, the only issue with this solution is that if the two fields are blank, it will return false. If you can fix that (even though I already did) just so anyone else look up this solution would not have the same problem.

Comment: @nolabel, you're correct, I neglected to make this method optional when fields are blank.  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Returning from the `.each()` iteration function doesn't return from the validator method; `.each()` just uses that to determine whether to keep iterating (the loop stops when the function returns `false`). You can use a variable that you update in the loop.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneNotEqual", function(value, element, param) {
    var valid = true;
    $(param).each(function() {
        if (value == this.value) {
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}, "The mobile, home, and work phone must be different.");
```

As far as I can tell, there's no way for the validation method to tailor the error message to the specific conditions that caused the failure. So it can't tell you which phone numbers were the same. You can use the technique in Sparky's answer to make the messages specific to the field.

Comment: very close solution. Sparky provided a solution to a message that works.